# addEventListener for loop doesn't respond

Tags: javascript

Please don't make it Duplicate, I just want to understand If I wrote my code wrong, All thought I checked it couple of times.

I can't understand way my code dosen't work.

Js:

```
var p1button = document.querySelector("#p1");
var p2button = document.getElementById("p1");

//p1 btn
for(var i = 0; i < p1button.length; i++){
    p1button[i].addEventListener("click", function(){
alert("clicked") });
 };
```

html:

```
<button id="p1">Player One</button>
         <button id="p2">Player Two</button>
```

My [codepen](https://codepen.io/nadav-himmelfarb/pen/LrYaGb)

Comment: Id's should be unique on a page, so p1button shouldn't be iterable

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't work because `p1button` is already an `ElementButton`, not an Array where you have to use `[0]` to get the element from.

```js
var p1button = document.querySelector("#p1");

p1button.addEventListener("click", function(){
  alert("clicked")
});
```

```html
<button id="p1">Player One</button>
```

whereas, is you had multiple **class** `.btn` elements your code would make sense, since `.getElementsByClassName` or `.querySelectorAll` do actually return an ***array-like*** **NodeList**:

```js
function doThaChng () {
  alert("clicked!");
}

var btn = document.querySelectorAll(".btn");

for(var i=0; i<btn.length; i++) {
 btn[i].addEventListener("click", doThaChng);
}
```

```html
<button class="btn">Player One</button>
<button class="btn">Player Two</button>
```

Or in ES6

```js
const btn = document.querySelectorAll(".btn");
const doThaChng = () => alert("Clicked");

[...btn].forEach(el => el.addEventListener("click", doThaChng) );
```

```html
<button class="btn">Player One</button>
<button class="btn">Player Two</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

`p1button` is not an array but a DOM element.

Try keeping just:

```
p1button.addEventListener("click", function(){
   alert("clicked") 
});
```

Comment: I've understood that buttons are like complex element that build out from couple of things and that's why I can't use the method you showed here, and I have to use a loop, can you check the answer to other question of mine here an explain it for me ? stackoverflow.com/questions/50592276/why-addeventlistener-only-work-with-for-loop?noredirect=1#comment88195402_50592276

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation of `querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector):

> The Document method querySelector() returns the **first Element within the document that matches the specified selector**, or group of selectors. If no matches are found, null is returned.

Try it out (open up Developer Tools to see the console):

```
console.log(document.querySelector("button"));
```

So you don't need (and you **can not**) iterate over `p1button`, because it's a node instead of an array.

Comment: So just to understand, there's node and array that is a nodeList?

Comment: So just to understand, there's node and array that is a nodeList?

Comment: @NadavHimmelfarb, sorry for naming mistake, I'm new in Javascript world, but here's the clarification: `querySelector()` returns an Element while `querySelectorAll()` returns NodeList, the latter can be iterated as an array (like you do in your example). See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_object_model/Locating_DOM_elements_using_selectors

Answer (score -1):

It's because `querySelector` and `getElementById` returns a single DOM element and not an array of DOM elements. So your for loop is useless and try to add an event listener on an `undefined` value.

Here is a correct way to listen for click event

```
var p1button = document.querySelector("#p1");    
p1button.addEventListener("click", function(){
  alert("clicked") 
});
```

Here you can find more infos about [querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) and [getElementById](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById).