# .style is not canging element

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have this script:

```
price2 = document.getElementById('price2');
price3 = document.getElementById('price3');

for (var i = 0; i < price2.length; i++) {
  price2[i].style.backgroundColor = 'orange';
}


<div class="single-car-prices">
  <div class="single-regular-price text-center" id="price2">
    <span class="labeled">Ціна</span>
    <span class="h3"> $ 1.500</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Why color of this div is still blue:

[image: output]

There is no errors in console, I think I wrote JS correctly

Comment: A `<div>` doesn’t have a `length` or numeric properties. What are you trying to loop over? Please read the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById) and try using the [debugging capabilities](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Debugging/Debugging_JavaScript) of your browser and test what `price2` is.

Comment: Related: [addEventListener for loop doesn't respond](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50601182/4642212).

Comment: you need to set background, not backgroundColor. Please, see my updated answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[getElementById](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById) takes always just one element. What you want is:

```
let price2 = document.getElementById('price2');
let price3 = document.getElementById('price3');


price2.style.color = 'orange';
```

**UPDATE:**

If you want to update `background`, then just use `background` property:

```
price2.style.background = 'orange';
```

An example:

```js
let price2 = document.getElementById('price2');
let price3 = document.getElementById('price3');

price2.style.background = 'orange';
```

```html
<div class="single-car-prices">
      <div class="single-regular-price text-center" id="price2">
        <span class="labeled">Ціна</span>
        <span class="h3"> $ 1.500</span>
      </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Guys, someone edited my question and added a snippet. I want to change div color, not 'Ціна $ 1.500' color

Comment: @Alex you need to set `background`, not `backgroundColor`. Please, see my updated answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

[getElementById](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById) gives you back exactly one element, so there is no reason to use any sort of `for` loop.

Are you trying to style multiple elements with this id? Then id is the wrong way to go, use classes, id can only appear once on a page.

```js
price2 = document.getElementById('price2');
price3 = document.getElementById('price3');

price2.style.color = 'orange';
```

```html
<div class="single-car-prices">
  <div class="single-regular-price text-center" id="price2">
    <span class="labeled">Ціна</span>
    <span class="h3"> $ 1.500</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Guys, someone edited my question and added a snippet. I want to change div color, not 'Ціна $ 1.500' color

Comment: @Alex You mean the background color? you can do that with `style.backgroundColor`. `style.color` changes the text color.

Comment: Ok, I wrote backgroundColor in the question